# Assertion failed (trackbar) in getTrackbarPos

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

How to fix the following error?

> OpenCV: terminate handler is called! The last OpenCV error is:
> OpenCV(4.5.5) Error: Assertion failed (trackbar) in getTrackbarPos,
> file C:\opencv-4.5.5\sources\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp, line 862

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
T PosToActual(T min, T max, int pos, int TICKS)
{
    return min + (max - min) * pos / TICKS;
}

void Refresh(int, void *data)
{
    Mat *original = (Mat *)data;

    Mat modified;
    vector<Mat> channels;
    split(*original, channels);

    int b = cv::getTrackbarPos("Blue", "Modified");
    int g = cv::getTrackbarPos("Green", "Modified");
    int r = cv::getTrackbarPos("Red", "Modified");

    channels[0] *= PosToActual<float>(0, 1, b, 10);
    channels[1] *= PosToActual<float>(0, 1, g, 10);
    channels[2] *= PosToActual<float>(0, 1, r, 10);

    merge(channels, modified);

    imshow("Modified", modified);
}

int main()
{
    const string filename = "family.jpg";

    Mat original = imread(filename);

    // Mat modified = Mat::zeros(original.size(), original.type());

    cv::namedWindow("Modified", WINDOW_NORMAL);
    int bFactor = 5;
    int gFactor = 5;
    int rFactor = 5;

    createTrackbar("Blue", "Modified", &bFactor, 10, Refresh, &original);
    createTrackbar("Green", "Modified", &gFactor, 10, Refresh, &original);
    createTrackbar("Red", "Modified", &rFactor, 10, Refresh, &original);

    Refresh(0, &original);

    waitKey();
}
```

## Edit:

This issue only occurs when using OpenCV for Windows (prebuilt) version

- 4.5.3
- 4.5.4
- 4.5.5

It works just fine for version 4.5.2. I have not checked for version lower than 4.5.2 yet because I am not interested in using any lower versions.

Comment: It is my old code and I think in the past I could run this. But today when I revisit this code, it fails to run. Is it a new bug?